# Passing ajax variable to more than one wordpress plugin function

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I'm trying to get information from the front end of my Wordpress site, I used ajax to do that, it gave me the ability to use the data in one of my plugin functions, but in my case I want to use this data in more than just one function.

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' ); 

function my_action_javascript() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'my_action',
            'whatever': 1234
        };

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data);
    });
    </script> <?php
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {

    $whatever = $_POST['whatever'];

}
```

In other words I need to use `$_POST['whatever']` in other functions in my plugin not only `my_action()` function, I tried using PHP global variables like so , but it didn't workout:

```
$whatever;
function my_action(){
    global $whatever = $_POST['whatever'];
}
function my_other_function(){
   global $whatever;
   if(isset($whatever)){
       echo $whatever;
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't merge them into 1 function, or use 1 function then call the others from it? It sounds like the structure of your code could be better organised, maybe if you provided some context as to what you're trying to do there may be alternatives suggested you hadn't considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a global variable, you have to set it outside any local scope, above your functions. For example:

```
if (isset($_POST['whatever'])) {
    $variable = $_POST['whatever'];
}
```

This will store it in the superglobal array. Now, access it using the `$_GLOBALS` array:

```
function my_action(){
   $whatever = $GLOBALS['variable'];
}
```

I would however have an easier approach. You can get the variable in one function and call the other one inside it. Take a look at this:

```
function first_func(){
    $variable = $_POST['whatever'];
    // Do whatever you want here
    echo "First $variable";
    // Now call the second one
    second_func($variable);
}
function second_func($input){
    echo $input;
}
```

Avoiding the globals is a good practice since you don't know what else could interfere with the array.

Comment: Thanks for you respond, but I can't use `isset($_POST['whatever']` outside `my_action()` function since it is not set only inside it, the second approach is good but I can't use my second function inside the first one.

Comment: @Berzerkfar If it is not set only inside it, then why can't you use it outside? by the way, why can't you use `$_POST[]` twice in both your functions?

Comment: Sorry I meant it is set only inside my_action function

Comment: because of the action `add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );`
`add_action( 'wp_ajax_<name of the function you want to use the variable>', '<name of the function you want to use the variable>' )`

Comment: @Berzerkfar When a data is sent using POST or GET method, it's set and accessible everywhere inside the `functions.php`. You can use `$GLOBALS['variable'] = $_POST['whatever'];` inside your first function, but your seconds function **must** run **after** the first function, or you can't retrieve the global variable.